OCR: Python tesseract optimizations
I'm using the code below to extract text from the following images:
import cv2
import pytesseract


# Configuration de Tesseract pour Windows
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'

# Charger l'image
image_path = 'C:/Users/Thomas Letellier/Pictures/simple.png'
# Load the image
img = cv2.imread(image_path)

# Convert to gry-scale
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Erode the image
erd = cv2.erode(gry, None, iterations=1)

# OCR with assuming the image as a single uniform block of text
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(erd, config="--oem 1 --psm 6 -l fra")

print (txt)

This code is working well with this image, I'm able to retrieve the name of the teams, the odds, etc...:

Here is the result (it's not perfect but good enough for my usage):
Combiné (3)
esse ]/
Nice
oO. ; 2,13
Résultat du match (tps rég.)
Auxerre + D (2) Nice
Lille
oO. ; 1,93
Résultat du match (tps rég.)
Reims | Le & Lille
Marseille
oO. ; 2,53
Résultat du match (tps rég.)
Brest Ÿ 1 0 Marseille
Cote totale 1040
Mise 0,10 €
Gains possibles 1,04€
03/08/24 22:13

My problem is that I'm not able to reproduce this result with the following image, I'm not able to retrieve the first soccer team name "Lens":

And here is my result:
Simple
Résultat du match (tps rég.)
Angers ÿ eu W Lens
Mise 0,10 €
Gains possibles 0,16 €
03/08/24 21:31

You can see that "Lens" is missing between "Simple" and the next line.
How can I improve the OCR feature ? I already tried all the available parameters (psm 1,2,3, etc...) but I'm probably missing something.
Thank you for your help,
Regards,
Thomas

what is the source link of your fra.traineddata? did you trained it on your own or got it from some site?
